# What says JAXB specification: XmlAnyAttribute collision with explicit mapped attribute

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

**Scenario**

Consider the following class (imports omitted):

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement
public class Test {

    @XmlAttribute
    public int id;

    @XmlAnyAttribute
    public Map<QName,String> any;

}
```

What is the behaviour when I do the following:

```
Test t = new Test();
t.id = 5;
t.any = new HashMap<QName,String>();
t.any.put(new QName("id"), "10");
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Test.class);
Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
m.setEventHandler(myEventHandler);
m.marshal(t, System.out);
```

**The obvious problem:**

An XML element should be generated for the instance of `Test`. But the obvious problem is: With which attributes? `<test id="5"/>`? Or `<test id="10"/>`? Or an invalid XML `<test id="5" id="10"/>`?

**Please answer:**

1. Will the marshalling be successful (or will there be an exception?)
2. Will `handleEvent(ValidationEvent)` of `myEventHandler` be called? If yes, with what?
3. What can be expected on System.out, i.e. what is the output XML? (If 1. is answered positive)
4. Will a (standard conforming) JAXB marshaller always generate well-formed XML? (No schema involved)
5. Is the behaviour of the reference implementation in the standard library, which outputs `<test id="5" id="10"/>` and reports *absolutely* no error, conforming to the JAXB specification?

**Please base your answer on solid fundaments:**

Of course one can just try it out. But one should be able to predict the exact behaviour with studying the Javadoc and JAXB specification documents. So, if possible, back your answer with citing the relevant part of a documentation source.

Comment: Y'know, you _could_ [download the JAXB spec](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr222/index2.html) and look at it yourself, and arguably if you're concerned about this kind of edge case that would be a good investment of your time. Assuming your employer's legal department doesn't object to the license agreement.

Comment: Honestly, I failed to find it out myself. I hope for guidance towards the solution. If an answer clarifies that the case isn't reglemented, that would be a step forward too. A seriously developed software should, IMHO, leave no doubts about behaviour in edge cases. While the concrete example may be considered as an edge case, point 4 is not. There must be some statement if the JAXB output is always well-formed XML or not.

Comment: I think the current behaviour is a bug: If you marshal it with a (corresponding) XML schema attached for validation, there is also no error reported! That means: The XML is not well-formed, but JAXB thinks it is valid w.r.t. to the schema. Unmarshalling fails with a parsing exception, because the XML is not well formed because of the double attribute declaration. This can't be correct!

Comment: Double attribute definition would indeed be a well-formedness problem. Either the reference implementation is broken, or your use of the reference implementation is broken. Given that others have been using the reference implementation correctly, I'd be more inclined to believe the latter.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but the last part is a pretty strong statement. A marshaller has the choice to handle the input (give well-formed XML) _or_ to interrupt and throw an exception (because it can't produce well-formed XML). There is no precondition violation from my side. If a marshaller can't handle certain input, it must clearly declare this as a precondition or/and indicate an error (via exception or other mechanism).

Comment: To support my last comment, see [Marshaller javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html): "The Marshaller class is responsible for governing the process of serializing Java content trees back into XML data. [...] A JAXB Provider must throw a MarshalException when it is unable to complete the marshal operation due to invalid content." One can assume that with "XML data" a well-formed XML is meant. Therefore the current behaviour is for me pretty certainly a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

### Where to Find the JAXB Specification

For reference the JAXB (JSR-222) specification can be downloaded from the following location:  https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222

### Answers to Your Questions

1. *Will the marshalling be successful (or will there be an exception?)*

   The JAXB 2.2 specification does not cover what will happen for this use case.  Only the unmarshalling use case is defined (see B.3.6.2).
2. *Will handleEvent(ValidationEvent) of myEventHandler be called? If yes, with what?*

   There is nothing in the JAXB 2.2 spec requiring this.
3. *What can be expected on System.out, i.e. what is the output XML? (If 1. is answered positive)*

   The behaviour for this is undefined.  As you pointed out both the reference and MOXy implementations of JAXB will output two attributes with the same name.
4. *Will a (standard conforming) JAXB marshaller always generate well-formed XML? (No schema involved)*

   You have identified one case where this is not true.
5. Is the behaviour of the reference implementation in the standard library, which outputs  and reports absolutely no error, conforming to the JAXB specification?

   The marshalling behviour is undefined in the specification, therefore the behaviour of the reference (and MOXy) implementations of JAXB don't conflict with the specification.

### Where to Report Issues

> A seriously developed software should, IMHO, leave no doubts about
>   behaviour in edge cases.

You can raise issues like this either through Jira or the mailing lists.

- https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB/ (Issue Tracker)
- https://java.net/projects/jaxb/lists/ (Mailing Lists)

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgement that this really is an undefined case. In a case where the spec doesn't define anything, the implementation should do the thing with least surprise for the user (in theory, it can do anything, you are right). I extended the example with XML schema validation and raised a ticket for both the [standard](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-999) and [MOXy implementation](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=426677). I did _not_ raise a ticket for a clarification of the standard. One step at a time :-)

Comment: I'll have to add a little criticism: Your answer to 4. implies that the implementation is standard conforming. I would say it is not :-) The marshaller javadocs say that "XML data" is output. If a file is not well-formed XML, it is not XML at all, so it's not "XML data". See my [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321665/what-says-jaxb-specification-xmlanyattribute-collision-with-explicit-mapped-att/21396585#comment32223131_21321665)